# C# how to put variables in the execution of commands

Tags: c#

the interface has many textboxes, currently I have to use something like the following:

```
private string[] preset_lines = new string[19];
    .....

      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox19.Text))
                {
                    preset_lines[18] = textBox19.Text;
                }
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox20.Text))
                {
                    preset_lines[19] = textBox20.Text;
                }
    .....
```

I hope I could put the sequence of textbox in a loop, so it will look like:

```
for (int i==0;i<20;i++)
{
 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox20.Text))
                    {
                        preset_lines[19] = textBoxi.Text;
                    }
}
```

any ideas how to do that? thanks

Comment: new string[19] has 19 elements, not 20, so present_lines[19] is off the end of the array.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution, which would not require you to refactor your code would be to put your textboxes in an array:

```
TextBox[] textBoxes = new []
{
    textBox1, textBox2, textBox3,
    textBox4, textBox5, textBox6,
    textBox7, textBox8, textBox9,
    textBox10, textBox11, textBox12,
    textBox13, textBox14, textBox15,
    textBox16, textBox17, textBox18,
    textBox19, textBox20
};
```

And then simply loop through them:

```
for(int i = 0; i < preset_lines.Length; i++)
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxes[i].Text))
       preset_lines[i] = textBoxes[i].Text;
```

Comment: but it reminds me "A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property", I guess need to modify the definition? I even tried  private dynamic  TextBox[] textBoxes = new[]..., but it reminds me again "textBox is a field but use as a type....

Answer (score 0):

You can also do foreach loop on all textboxes in your Controls:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Text))
                {
                    preset_lines[19] = c.Text;
                }
            }
        }
```

By the way, your for loop will not compile (since you should declare integer i = 0):

```
for (int i==0;i<20;i++)
```

It should be:

```
for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
```

Comment: This is always setting (and overriding) the value of `preset_lines[19]`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to use "right tool for the job" - `DataGridView`

```
private BindingList<string> presetLines;

public YourForm()
{
    var tempList = Enumerable.Repeat(string.Empty, 20).ToList();
    _presetLines = new BindingList(tempList);
    yourDataGridView.DataSource = _presetLines;
}
```

When you update value in `DataGridView` it will automatically updates a `BindingList`.

If you don't want empty values you can filter them when you using it

```
var notEmptyValues = presetLines.Where(value => String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) == false);
```